# Class imported from module do not match with class accessed from module

Tags: python

I have following code

```
import imp
from my_module import MyClass
import my_module

imp.reload(my_module)
print(MyClass == my_module.MyClass) # Result is False
```

Why the `MyClass` imported from `my_module` is not equal to `my_module.MyClass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is hidden at the line, where you reload your module. After such reload, python recompiles the whole module, recreate all objects inside it and load it.

So, when reloading module, there is created completely new class `MyClass` that is not the same object as it was before.

You can check this code:

```
import imp
from my_module import MyClass
import my_module
print(MyClass == my_module.MyClass) # Result is True
imp.reload(my_module)
print(MyClass == my_module.MyClass) # Result is False
```

Comment: When testing class equality, you normally use the `is` operator.